# Xamarin Forms Maps: Pin click stops working after changing / replacing pin

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

- I create a Xamarin.Forms.Maps map for iOS.
- I add some pins
- I add click handlers to the pins

These all work fine

The user now drags the map and fire my onDrag handler

I then want to refresh the pins to reflect the new view area
This works too - except now the Clicked event on the pins is ignored. The info box is displayed, but the handler itself is never called when I click the info box. This works when first set but not after the pins are changed.

I have tried creating new pins on drag:

```
map.Pins.Clear();
foreach (Place p in PlaceList){
  Pin newPin = new Pin();
  pin.Label = p.PlaceName;
  pin.Clicked += DoPinClick;
}
```

and then I tried reusing the existing pins on drag:

```
Pin pin;
for (int i = 0; i < PlaceList.Count; i++) {
  if (i > 9)
    // max of 10 pins
    break;
  Place p = PlaceList [i];
  if (i >= map.Pins.Count - 1) {
    // a new pin to be created and added to the map pins
    pin = new Pin();
    pin.Clicked += DoPinClick;
    pin.Label = p.PlaceName;
    map.Pins.Add (pin);
  } else {
    // there was already a pin in that slot, get it and reuse it
    pin = map.Pins [i];
    pin.Label = p.PlaceName;
  }
  pin.Position = p.Position;
  // copy the pin into the slot it occupies already
  map.Pins [i] = pin;
}
```

But whichever approach I follow the event handler only works until I change the pins.

Comment: It may not matter but have you tried removing the event handlers before you clear the existing list?

Comment: I hadn't, but I've just tried and no difference.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a bug on Xamarin's end.

[Bug report 25557](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=25557)

[Bug report 29017](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=29017)

Comment: No these are earlier bugs that stopped the event firing at all. I am on xamarin.forms.maps 1.4.2.6355 and the event does now fire - until I change the Map.Pins collection, then it never fires again

Comment: Hmm, I'm doing the same thing in my app so it seems like a good bet that I'm about to run into this as well.